# Appending a value to python dictionary value using the key if the value is a multiple array

Tags: python, dictionary

I declared a python dictionary with key and value as multiple array. Is it possible to append an array using the key and value index?

This is the way I initialized the python dictionary cvfoldacc

```
a = []
b = [] 
c = [] 
d = [] 
e = [] 
f = []
classifiers = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
cvfoldacc = dict.fromkeys(range(2,11), classifiers)
```

And the result of this initialization is as follows:

```
cvfoldacc>>

{2: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 3: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 4: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 5: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 6: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 7: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 8: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 9: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 10: [[], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

When I tried to append the first list of key(2) with the code 
cvfoldacc[2][0].append(8), I am getting the result as:

```
{2: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 3: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 4: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 5: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 6: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 7: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 8: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 9: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 10: [[8], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

But the expected answer should be this:

```
{2: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 3: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 4: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 5: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 6: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 7: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 8: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 9: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 10: [[], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)

Comment: No.It says about the list appending procedure

Comment: You need to create separate list for each key

Comment: The results are same even after creating separate list for every key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new `list`s for values of each `key` like,

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [] 
>>> c = [] 
>>> d = [] 
>>> e = [] 
>>> f = []
>>> classifiers = [a,b,c,d,e,f] 
>>> 
>>> d = {k:[x[:] for x in classifiers] for k in range(2,11)} # note i am creating a copy using the `list[:]` notation.
# either the comprehension or `k: copy.deepcopy(classifiers)` is fine
>>> d
{2: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 3: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 4: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 5: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 6: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 7: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 8: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 9: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 10: [[], [], [], [], [], []]}
>>> d[2][0].append(1)
>>> d
{2: [[1], [], [], [], [], []], 3: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 4: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 5: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 6: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 7: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 8: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 9: [[], [], [], [], [], []], 10: [[], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

Comment: Yes, you could do it either way you like, for your current structure

Comment: Great. Glad to be able to help :)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same old `deep copy` vs `shallow copy` thing.
Try this:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = [] 
>>> c = [] 
>>> d = [] 
>>> e = [] 
>>> f = []
>>> classifiers = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
>>> import copy
>>> cvfoldacc = {k:copy.deepcopy(classifiers) for k in range(2,11)}
>>> cvfoldacc[2][0].append(8)
>>> cvfoldacc 
{2: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 3: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 4: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 5: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 6: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 7: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 8: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 9: [[], [], [], [], [], []],
 10: [[], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

You were doing:

```
a = []
b = [] 
c = [] 
d = [] 
e = [] 
f = []
classifiers = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
cvfoldacc = dict.fromkeys(range(2,11), classifiers)
```

Now, the dictionary that is getting created, has the same list in every key, not only they look same, those are the exact same objects, having same `identity` (memory location in CPython). Let's see:

```
>>> id(cvfoldacc[2])
171760008
>>> id(cvfoldacc[3])
171760008
```

And these will be same for other values as well.
So `dict.fromkeys()` assigns the same value to all the keys in the dictionary, does not create a copy of it.

Now, another way, where you make a shallow copy, and this issue would be solved:

```
>>> cvfoldacc = {a:classifiers.copy() for a in range(2,11)}
>>> id(cvfoldacc[2])
171840616
>>> id(cvfoldacc[3])
171847688
```

Solved right?

```
>>> cvfoldacc[2][0].append(8)
{2: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 3: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 4: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 5: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 6: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 7: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 8: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 9: [[8], [], [], [], [], []],
 10: [[8], [], [], [], [], []]}
```

Apparently not!! Let's now look DEEPER. Let's look at the `id`s of the lists inside the lists:

```
>>> id(cvfoldacc[2][0])
171810120
>>> id(cvfoldacc[3][0])
171810120
```

So even though `list.copy()` created a copy of the outerlist, the inner lists are the same. So essentially you are appending in `list: a` which is present in all the `keys` so everything is getting modified.

[`Deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) copied all the objects recursively, avoiding the issue.

Comment: Could you please explain why the previous method did'nt worked..

Comment: Sure, it will take a little time to write it up.

Comment: do ```[id(cvfoldacc[x]) for x in range(2,11)]``` for your original code. You'll see they are all the same ID - so you only made references to one list. Now do ```id(classifiers)```.  Make a change like ```classifiers[0] = [1,2]```.  See how it propagates through your dict? That means you made a dict whose values are all references to that original list. This is particularly an issue with any nested sequence.  So you always need to make sure you're instantiating new objects in this situation.

Comment: A useful information about the referencing of lists. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Also note, the other answer does the same thing, without importing `copy`. Make sure you understand the innerworkings. `{k:[x[:] for x in classifiers] for k in range(2,11)}` here `x[:]` serves as `deepcopy` as it creates a new copy of `a,b,c,d,e,f` in every iteration.